# "Applications of intuitionistic logic"

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, closed-questions

[This my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164553/applications-of-intuitionistic-logic) was closed today, and I don't understand why. Can anybody explain to me what was wrong with this question and why it was closed?

Comment: It's been reopened, I placed the last vote. I was of the opinion that not enough context was given, apart from a source, but I realize that this is an advanced subject so not everybody is expected to understand all the terminologies present, and the question is about okay as it stands for that reason. Having said that, if you have further sources which you have consulted then you may add them, and please add sources for propositional intuitionistic calculus (which is your example). This will probably make the question better than it is right now.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon. I have added some references.

Comment: Thank you! If I had any problem with it earlier, I don't have one now.